# Strange behavior with returns in try blocks in groovy

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

Take this snippet:

```
def line = "asdf"

String foo() {
  try {
     //line = "qwer"
     return line
  } finally {
     line = "zxcv"
  }
}

println line
println foo()
println line
```

Coming from a .NET background I would expect the print lines to produce

```
asdf
asdf
zxcv
```

In groovy however, it produces

```
asdf
zxcv
asdf
```

Which boggles me in a few ways.

1) Why does printing the value of `foo()` produce `zxcv`?  I would expect the return statement to evaluate `line` and attempt to return `asdf`, but before returning set line to `asdf` which shouldn't affect the return value.

2) Since the second output is `zxcv`, we must accept that the line `line = "zxcv"` IS getting executed.  Why then, is it getting set BACK to `asdf` for the third output?

3) Uncommenting the `line = "qwer"` line produces the output looks like:

```
asdf
qwer
asdf
```

which I see as inconsistent with either model.  It looks like some strange scoping behavior, but I can't figure out what the rules are here.

Using Groovy 2.2.2

**EDIT:** AHA! I am running this from groovy console.  It appears that if I wrap this in a class, and run it, the program produces the expected output ie:

```
class MyClass {
    def line = "asdf"

    String foo() {
      try {
         //line = "qwer"
         return line
      } finally {
         line = "zxcv"
      }
    }

    def printStuff() {    
      println line
      println foo()
      println line
    }
}

new MyClass().printStuff()
```

produces

```
asdf
asdf
zxcv
```

I have also discovered the *Script -> Clear Script Context* menu option.  When executing the original snippet immediately after clearing the script context, the console will throw the following exception:

```
asdf
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: line for class: ConsoleScript53

    at ConsoleScript53.foo(ConsoleScript53:6)

    at ConsoleScript53.run(ConsoleScript53:13)
```

Subsequent runs produce the incorrect output

```
asdf
zxcv
asdf
```

Armed with this new information, it seems that there's some weirdness in GroovyConsole that is lifting `line` into it's context, and returning that instead of the `line` declared at the top.  Or something.  Knowing it's just a problem with a tool and not the language keeps me from wanting to run screaming from this language which I was just starting to really enjoy.

Comment: i can't reproduce this. could you make a SSCCE and include how you execute it (from command line, in groovy console, etc.) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22 will explain the situation a bit.

Basically you should remove the `def` in the first line to get the .Net result.

But I have to to put myself together with Nathan here, your program does not normally produce the output you said it does. And that is because if you have read the linked page, you will know, that the `line` in `foo()` is referencing the binding, while the `line` outside `foo()` is a local variable, that is independent of the binding. So the expected result is to get a `MissingPropertyException` for when executing `return line`. And that is because `line` does not exist in the binding before you have written there the first time.

To produce the output you have seen, you need to actually add a

```
line = "zxcv"
```

before the `def`. This will ensure `line` has a existence in the binding. Adding it after the `def` would write the local variable and you would have to use `binding.line` instead. To make things more easy I give the full program again here:

```
line = "zxcv"
def line = "asdf"

String foo() {
  try {
     //line = "qwer"
     return line
  } finally {
     line = "zxcv"
  }
}

println line
println foo()
println line
```

So given this *corrected* program I can answer your questions:

1. Printing the value of `foo()` produces `zxcv` because that is what the value of line was when entering the function. If you change the first line to use for example `123`, then `123` is what you would get instead of `zxcv`.
2. The line `line = "zxcv"` is indeed executed and changes what is stored in the binding. But it does not change what the method will return, so you would get the same result even if you changed that to assign `foobar` to line. And since the third `println` is reading from the local variable instead of the binding the missing visible effect of `foo()` is also explained.
3. Uncommenting the `line = "qwer"` in the original program will ensure you have something in the binding, thus you wouldn't get the `MissingPropertyException`. But `foo()` will still return what was in the binding before the `finally` block was executed, thus you get `qwer` back.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  This all makes much better sense, and the link helps too.  Running the script multiple times without clearing the script context (thus resetting the bindings) was the reason I wasn't getting the `MissingPropertyException`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java (and Groovy of course) the finally block is always executed, and it executes before the  method ends, unless, you call  System.exit()  or the JVM crashes.

In java the Strings are inmutable, every time you change a  string value you create a new object.

So the first line is and the second line refers to different objects.

Comment: First, if the finally block exits before the return call, then uncommenting `line = "qwer"` shouldn't make any difference in the output.  Second, I'm not mutating any string.  I'm assigning a string to the variable `line`.  I don't think this is the right answer.